# PyAutoGui LocateOnScreen() - multiple locations

Tags: pyautogui

How does this function work if there are several exact images on the screen?
I'm trying to write a program that goes down a list of rows, checks for that image, if there, click, then keep looping.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to do that, you should use `locateAllOnScreen()`.

Comment: Working!. Example source:
import pyautogui
    locations = pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen('childImage.png', confidence=0.8)
    for location in locations:
      print(location)